# The child component doesn't disappear when the height of the parent component is animated to 0

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I want to have a dropdown box that could appear and disappear by increase/decrease in its box.  Currently it's appearing by having its height increased, but doesn't disappear when the height is decreased. More specifically, the height is being decreased, but the text element, which is the child component, is not disappearing.

[image]

The screen component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Dimensions,
    ScrollView,
    SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native'

import Panel from '../components/help/Panel'

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')

export default Help = () => {

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
                <Panel title="Question 1" >
                    <Text> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</Text>
                </Panel>
                <Panel title="A Panel with long content text">
                    <Text>Lorem ipsum...</Text>
                </Panel>
                <Panel title="Another Panel">
                    <Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</Text>
                </Panel>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: width * .90,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
})
```

Panel.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Animated,    
} from 'react-native'
import { moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters'
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign"

export default Panel = ({ title, children }) => {
    const [isExpanded, expand] = useState(false)
    const [minHeight, setMinHeight] = useState()
    const [maxHeight, setMaxHeight] = useState()
    const [animation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))


    const _setMinHeight = e => {
        setMinHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height)
    }
    const _setMaxHeight = e => {
        setMaxHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height)
    }

    const toggle = () => {
        let initialValue = isExpanded ? maxHeight + minHeight : minHeight
        let finalValue = isExpanded ? minHeight : maxHeight + minHeight
        animation.setValue(initialValue)
        Animated.spring(animation,{
            toValue: finalValue,
            duration: 1500,
        }).start(() => {
            expand(!isExpanded)                            
        })
    }

    return (
        <View style={[styles.container]}>
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={styles.questionContainer}
                onLayout={_setMinHeight}
                onPress={toggle}
            >
                <Text style={styles.questionText}>{title}</Text>
                <Icon 
                    name={isExpanded ? "caretup" : "caretdown"} 
                    size={moderateScale(15)} 
                    style={styles.icon}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Animated.View 
                style={[styles.answerContainer, { height: animation }]}
                onLayout={_setMaxHeight}
            >
                {children}
            </Animated.View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container   : {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        margin:10,
    },
    questionContainer : {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    questionText: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 10,
        color:'#2a2f43',
        fontWeight:'bold'
    },
    icon: {
        paddingTop: 10,  
    },
    answerContainer: {
        padding: 10,
        paddingTop: 0,
        overflow:'hidden'        
    }
})
```

**Update**
Actually, the height is being unpredictable, which I'm not sure why.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on your code for a long time
This is a little better
He was acting strangely perhaps because he was updating the state in a circular and uncontrollable way

````
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Animated, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/index';
import {moderateScale} from 'react-native-size-matters';

export default class PanelClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.isExpanded = false;
    this.animation = new Animated.Value(15);
  }

  toggle = () => {
    let initialValue = this.isExpanded ? 50 : 15;
    let finalValue = this.isExpanded ? 15 : 50;

    this.animation.setValue(initialValue);

    Animated.spring(this.animation, {
      toValue: finalValue,
      duration: 1000,
    }).start(() => {
      this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container]}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.questionContainer}
          onPress={this.toggle}>
          <Text style={styles.questionText}>
            {this.props.title}
          </Text>
          <Icon
            name={this.state.isExpanded ? 'caretup' : 'caretdown'}
            size={moderateScale(15)}
            style={styles.icon}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.answerContainer, {height: this.animation}]}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```
````